# How can I run "exo-preferred-applications" on Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I have just installed the latest version of kali linux:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ lsb_release -a                                                          1 ⨯
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    2020.4
Codename:   kali-rolling
```

And I am trying to update my default terminal emulator by using `exo-preferred-applications`. It is not installed on my computer despite the package being listed as installed. I have tried using `sudo apt install --reinstall exo-utils` but I have had no luck.

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt search exo-preferred-applications
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
exo-utils/kali-rolling,now 4.16.0-1 amd64 [installed]
  Utility files for libexo

                                                                                
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ which exo-preferred-applications
exo-preferred-applications not found
```

Comment: Try sudo apt autoremove and then try to install the apps again.

Comment: I tried that, but sadly it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Looks like after the most recent release, it has been deleted. and the correct thing to use is xfce4-settings. There are more details in the xfce git issues [here](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/exo/-/issues/51#note_21045)

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install kali-linux-default  See:  https://simontaplin.net/2019/03/29/how-to-install-all-the-penetration-testing-tools-in-kali-linux-for-windows-subsystem-for-linux/   .  That might get the packages you need.